# Swift compiler in Xcode 6.3 failing on simple use of the '+' operator

Tags: swift, xcode6.3

Trying to use Swift is just getting ridiculous.  I updated Xcode from 6.2 to 6.3 and now the compiler is complaining about simple addition.  The source line is this, where passKeyData is an NSData item:

```
let u8Value : UInt8 = 3 + passKeyData.length as UInt8 + 1
```

Swift is complaining about "Ambiguous use of the '+' operator".

Comment: Casting is not the same as coercion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a slightly misleading error message, but...

`NSData.length` returns an `Int`, and you can't convert from an `Int` value to a `UInt8` using `as`.  You need to explicitly construct a `UInt8` like so:

```
let u8Value : UInt8 = 3 + UInt8(passKeyData.length) + 1
```

You also may want to either check the value doesn't exceed `UInt8.max` (or else you'll get a runtime failure), or use `UInt8(truncatingBitPattern: x)` if you don't mind truncating it down to fit.

Comment: If this resolved your issue, you can accept the answer by clicking the check next to it.